# How to allow custom post type (add, edit, delete) for subscriber users in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

This is my custom post type code and i want to give add, edit, delete permission to subscribers user.

How to allow custom post type (add, edit, delete) for subscriber users in wordpress. Please help me guys Thanks in advance.

```
add_action( 'init', 'realestate_init' );
        function realestate_init() {
        $labels = array(
            'name'               => _x( 'Realestates', 'post type general name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
            'singular_name'      => _x( 'Realestate', 'post type singular name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
            'menu_name'          => _x( 'Realestates', 'admin menu', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
            'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Realestate', 'add new on admin bar', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
            'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'realestate', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
            'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Realestate', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
            'new_item'           => __( 'New Realestate', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
            'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Realestate', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
            'view_item'          => __( 'View Realestate', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
            'all_items'          => __( 'All Realestates', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
            'search_items'       => __( 'Search Realestates', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
            'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Realestates:', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
            'not_found'          => __( 'No realestates found.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No realestates found in Trash.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' )
        );
        $args = array(
            'labels'             => $labels,
            'description'        => __( 'Description.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
            'public'             => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui'            => true,
            'show_in_menu'       => true,
            'query_var'          => true,
            'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'realestate' ),
            'capability_type'    => 'post',
            'has_archive'        => true,
            'hierarchical'       => false,
            'menu_position'      => null,
            'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
        );
        register_post_type( 'realestate', $args );
    }
    // End register custom post type
```

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14553/allow-member-to-have-access-to-custom-post-type-only-permission-to-only-edit-th

Answer (score 1):

To simplify this process, let’s use a function that a roles and assigns them all capabilities required manage **(add,edit,publish,delete)** our custom post type.

```
function add_custom_caps() {
    // gets the subscriber role
    $role = get_role( 'subscriber' );

    // This only works, because it accesses the class instance.
    // would allow the subscriber to edit others' posts for current theme only
     $role->add_cap( 'read' );
     $role->add_cap( 'read_post');
     $role->add_cap( 'read_private_post' );
     $role->add_cap( 'edit_post' );
     $role->add_cap( 'edit_others_post' );
     $role->add_cap( 'edit_published_post' );
     $role->add_cap( 'publish_post' );
     $role->add_cap( 'delete_others_post' );
     $role->add_cap( 'delete_private_post' );
     $role->add_cap( 'delete_published_post' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_custom_caps');
```

This code is fairly straight forward. We have a the `WP_Role` object of the current role, then adds our new `_post` capabilities to said role using the WordPress `add_cap()` function. See the [get_role() function on the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_role) to get a better understanding of what capabilities are available.

Comment: Thanks Purvik, But where to specify custom post type name in this function?

Comment: @rartheme no need to add custom post type name, It's only needed `capability_type ` and you already have mention this `'capability_type'    => 'post',`.

Comment: @purvik7373 I am also looking for aloowing subscriber user role to add/edit/delete my custom post. I followed the steps defined above. But still it shows me an error : Sorry, you are not allowed to create posts as this user when I am signed in as a subscriber

Comment: Please can you help me?